# How to set column or rows in a raster to NA (or another value) in R?

Tags: r, raster

I have a raster that I want to set the outer rows or columns to NA (or specific value).  Setting the 1st row and last row is reasonably straightforward as I know the cell numbers of the 1st and last rows as the cell numbers start at 1 and increase with the number of columns in each row.  I know the cell numbers of my example raster (with say 10 columns) using:

```
ids <- init(exampleraster, v='cell')
```

I could then set the 1st row to NA using:

```
ids[ids < 11] <- NA
```

I could then set the values of ids all to 1:

```
ids[ids > 1] <- 1
```

and then multiply by the example raster:

```
newraster <- ids*exampleraster
```

This however appears unelegant - is there a better way?

However, setting the 1st and last column is much more tricky because the cell numbers increase in jumps of the number of columns i.e. the cell number of the 1st cell in the 1st column is 1, but the second is a multiple of the number of columns (e.g. if there were 100 columns in the raster then the 2nd cell would have a cell number of 101).  How could I set a specific column to NA?

Any help would be appreciated, Antony

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming we're talking about a `raster` object, then:

```
library(raster)
r <- raster(matrix(runif(100), 10))

r[c(cellFromRow(r, c(1, nrow(r))), 
    cellFromCol(r, c(1, ncol(r))))] <- NA
```

As alluded to in my comment below, you can also subset a raster as if it were a matrix, and this includes subsetting it *with* a matrix. The following is likely to be faster than the approach above:

```
r[as.matrix(rbind(expand.grid(c(1, nrow(r)), seq_len(ncol(r))),
                  expand.grid(seq_len(nrow(r)), c(1, ncol(r)))))]  <- NA
```

Comment: Great thanks.  I guess I can just use targetecells[cellFromCol(targetecells, 7314)]  <- NA if I want to set the 7314th column to NA in targetecells.

Comment: @user2901667 yes, yes you can. But you could also do `targetecells[, 7314] <- NA`.

Comment: Thanks - using your last suggestion targetecells[, 7314] <- NA, how does it know if it is a column or a row?

Comment: `targetecells[, 7314]` is column 7314, while `targetecells[7314, ]` is row 7314. Note the position of the comma. (Similarly, `targetecells[6, 7314]` refers to row 6, column 7314.)